# How can I move an email from a directory to another using python

Tags: python, email, bots, imaplib

I am facing a problem that I can't solve despite many searches.

It is the following: the goal is to change the directory of an email (for example, an email is in the spam and we want to move it to the inbox).

For the handling of the mailbox, I use the imaplib library (the IMAP4_SSL module in particular). I'm new to using this library and maybe that's why I can't find a solution. I specify that I want to explicitly move the message and not copy it to the desired location and then delete it.

I tried to do this but without success:

```
ok, uids = self.connexion.search(None, "ALL HEADER From 'test_bot'")
mail_ids = uids[0].decode().split()
resp_code, response = self.connexion.uid("MOVE", mail_ids[0], "[Gmail]/Spam")
```

The values of resp_code and response are respectively OK, [None]

If you can help me, I would be grateful, any proposal is good to take even if you have to use another library.

Have a nice day.

Comment: What actually happens? See [ask] and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953)

Comment: If you ask what happens when I run the lines of code I provide then pretty much nothing except it returns values for resp_code and response but when I check the mailbox nothing has changed.

Comment: You’re mixing mail sequence numbers and UIDs. You need to use UID SEARCH to get UIDs for UID MOVE.  With plain SEARCH you get MSNs which are completely different namespace of numbers. So you’re moving random stuff, which may not exist.

Comment: ok, uids = self.connexion.uid("SEARCH", "ALL HEADER From 'test_bot'")

mail_ids = uids[0].decode().split()

resp_code, response = self.connexion.uid("MOVE", mail_ids[0], "[Gmail]/Spam")

Like that @Max ? Because I tried but it does not change much except that the uid of the mail increase by one each time I try to move it.

Comment: Are you looking at the ALL Mail folder?  It never leaves there.

Answer (score 0):

```
from imap_tools import MailBox

with MailBox('imap.mail.com').login('test@mail.com', 'pwd', 'INBOX') as mailbox:
    # MOVE all messages from current folder to INBOX/folder2
    mailbox.move(mailbox.uids(), 'INBOX/folder2')
```

https://github.com/ikvk/imap_tools

I am lib author

Comment: Is it possible to use your library with AWS Lambda?

Comment: @HansDesjarlais, my lib work with IMAP protocol, so - any calculator with IMAP